# How to set style to edit-text android?

Tags: android

I have an edit-text that I want to make bold special words in it. Everything I found was about the text-view. How make bold a word in edit-text?

[image: screen record]

Comment: You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to bold specific words (even with `Drawable` items if you want to) from the text input. I use it to create a list of frequency values with Chip drawable behind each frequency value when a user enters valid frequency values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use textListener and set text bold run time i.e.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int count, int after) {
} 

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count) {
   if(boldSelected){
     String boldString = "<b>" + s + "</b> ";
     editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(boldString));
    }
}
});
```

Something like this. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

**XML**:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="#E0E8EF"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

**By program:**

```
 usertext.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Assume usertext as your EditText

Comment: So, the text which you wish to make bold will be a particular word or depends on user wish ?

Comment: If the boldertext comes after a particular position in edit text then implement Textchanged listener and check the length using if condition on onTextchanged method and set the Typeface for the characters using substring method

Comment: Any success attempt?

Comment: I add a video to the post. I want to make a part of the text to bold and save it to my database.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your problem

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name;
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

Comment: This is for text-view. I want to add text bold in the edit-text while the user is typing.

Comment: You use need to do it runtime according to your need, but same code will work that i shared

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`yourTextView.setPaintFlags(yourTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);`